# ¿Como combino 2 condiciones o más en una misma consulta en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, select, distinct

He estado probando con diferente combinaciones de condiciones en una consulta, ya que entiendo debe haber más de una condición para que pueda obtener los valores que necesito, entre ellas DISTINCT y SELECT MAX, pero no logro combinarlas como corresponde.

Lo que quiero es obtener los valores de la columna mascarillas_sol de la fecha más reciente de cada una de las instituciones. Para este caso, que me entregue el 2 y el 4.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he intentado, según mi lógica, con:

```
SELECT `mascarillas_sol` FROM reportes WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT institucion FROM reportes AND fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM reportes));
```

Pero me da error de sintax.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una `subquery` que busque las mascarillas_sol para cada institución ordenando por fecha dentro de la `query` que diferencia las instituciones.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE reportes (
  id INT,
  institucion VARCHAR(100),
  mascarillas_sol TINYINT,
  fecha DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO reportes (id,institucion,mascarillas_sol,fecha) VALUES (1,"institucion1",1,"2020-05-13 00:00:01"), (2,"institucion1",2,"2020-05-13 00:00:03"),(3,"institucion2",3,"2020-05-13 00:00:02"),(4,"institucion2",4,"2020-05-13 00:00:04");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.institucion,
( 
  SELECT r2.mascarillas_sol
  FROM reportes r2 where r.institucion=r2.institucion
  ORDER BY r2.fecha DESC LIMIT 1
) as mascarillas_sol
FROM reportes r

;

| institucion  | mascarillas_sol |
| ------------ | --------------- |
| institucion1 | 2               |
| institucion2 | 4               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: ¡Gracias!, lo hice tal cual me dijiste y pude obtener lo que quería.